# Undefined reference to objects from the core library when compiling Rust for RTL8710

Tags: rust, arm, embedded, microcontroller

I'm working with Rust and RTL8710 and had success running the example provided [according to this guide](https://polyfractal.com/post/rustl8710/). Problems start when I use the alloc or freertos packages.

```
pub use alloc::arc::Arc;
// ...
let serialArc = Arc::new(serial);
//...
```

Using `Arc` leads to `undefined reference to 'core::panicking::panic'`:

```
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.4ypvbwho0bu5tnww.rcgu.o): In function `<core::option::Option<T>>::unwrap':
/Users/admin/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.57k06xfugllsc526.rcgu.o): In function `core::sync::atomic::fence':
/Users/admin/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
/Users/admin/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.3ik0x0hz6l66cx38.rcgu.o): In function `core::sync::atomic::atomic_sub':
/Users/admin/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
```

I solved this somehow with a workaround:

```
#[export_name = "_ZN4core9panicking5panic17h89270e21a9d28c4fE"]
pub fn except_add_overflow() -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

When I try to use freertos functionality:

```
extern crate freertos_rs;

use super::*;
use prelude::v1::*;
use freertos_rs::*;
use freertos_rs::patterns::compute_task::*;

// use ctypes::c_void;
use serial::{Serial, SerialPort};

//
pub extern "C" fn rtos_example(serial: &mut Serial) {
    let queue = Arc::new(freertos_rs::Queue::new(10).unwrap());
    // let serialArc = Arc::new(serial);

    let read_task = {
        let queue = queue.clone();
        let mut serial = serial.clone();
        Task::new()
            .name("serial_read")
            .compute(move || {
                serial.rx_i32();
                queue.send(1, Duration::ms(1000)).unwrap();
            })
            .unwrap()
    };
}
```

It gets much worse with more missing methods from the core package:

```
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.3vxbyj3yk65hqzni.rcgu.o): In function `main_entry':
/Workspace/rustl8710/src/rust/src/lib.rs:50: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.8xzrsc1ux72v29j.rcgu.o): In function `<&'a T as core::fmt::Display>::fmt':
/Users/k1x/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs:1561: undefined reference to `<str as core::fmt::Display>::fmt'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.4ypvbwho0bu5tnww.rcgu.o): In function `<core::option::Option<T>>::unwrap':
/Users/k1x/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.16u6js6g0l3k1ic6.rcgu.o): In function `core::result::unwrap_failed':
/Users/k1x/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:23: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic_fmt'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.52iob5qgp6iyvrqp.rcgu.o): In function `<freertos_rs::units::DurationImpl<T>>::ms':
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/units.rs:42: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.57k06xfugllsc526.rcgu.o): In function `core::sync::atomic::fence':
/Users/k1x/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
/Users/k1x/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.3ik0x0hz6l66cx38.rcgu.o): In function `core::sync::atomic::atomic_add':
/Users/k1x/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.3ik0x0hz6l66cx38.rcgu.o): In function `core::sync::atomic::atomic_sub':
/Users/k1x/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/macros.rs:20: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
application/Debug/rust_obj/libfreertos_rs.o(freertos_rs-15ec896420c1dd77.freertos_rs6.rcgu.o): In function `<T as core::convert::Into<U>>::into':
/Users/k1x/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/libcore/convert.rs:415: undefined reference to `<alloc::string::String as core::convert::From<&'a str>>::from'
application/Debug/rust_obj/libfreertos_rs.o(freertos_rs-15ec896420c1dd77.freertos_rs6.rcgu.o): In function `<freertos_rs::base::FreeRtosError as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt':
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::Formatter::debug_tuple'
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::Formatter::debug_tuple'
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::Formatter::debug_tuple'
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::Formatter::debug_tuple'
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::Formatter::debug_tuple'
application/Debug/rust_obj/libfreertos_rs.o(freertos_rs-15ec896420c1dd77.freertos_rs6.rcgu.o):/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: more undefined references to `core::fmt::Formatter::debug_tuple' follow
application/Debug/rust_obj/libfreertos_rs.o(freertos_rs-15ec896420c1dd77.freertos_rs6.rcgu.o): In function `<freertos_rs::base::FreeRtosError as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt':
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::builders::DebugTuple::finish'
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::builders::DebugTuple::finish'
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::builders::DebugTuple::finish'
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::builders::DebugTuple::finish'
/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: undefined reference to `core::fmt::builders::DebugTuple::finish'
application/Debug/rust_obj/libfreertos_rs.o(freertos_rs-15ec896420c1dd77.freertos_rs6.rcgu.o):/Users/k1x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/freertos_rs-0.2.0/src/base.rs:2: more undefined references to `core::fmt::builders::DebugTuple::finish' follow
```

My Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "rustl8710"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["polyfractal <zach@zacharytong.com>"]

[dependencies]
freertos_rs = "0.2"

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"

[lib]
name = "rustl8710"
crate-type=["lib"]

#[dependencies.lazy_static]
#version = "0.2.1"
#features = ["nightly", "spin_no_std"]
```

And my Xargo.toml:

```
[target.thumbv7m-none-eabi.dependencies]
alloc = {}
```

I had a guess that that the core functionality is missing from all the libraries except the main one. In order to test this guess, I added a `panic` in the main method and get:

```
application/Debug/rust_obj/librustl8710.o(rustl8710-604cf36bb12750fc.3vxbyj3yk65hqzni.rcgu.o): In function `main_entry':
/Workspace/rustl8710/src/rust/src/lib.rs:50: undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic'
```

Is there any way to fix these missing objects?

Comment: Can you please post your xargo command? Also, is there a way to get the source, so one could try this?